# Can I display scene strips in wireframe, solid, and lookdev mode in vse?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I did some testing and found that SceneStrip can be used for vse, but only displays the renderview for each engine.

Version 2.79 of the vse has a scene preview / render tab that allows you to use different shading modes on the scene strip. (Even vse preview screen shows selected object and active object.)

Has this feature been removed in version 2.8? Or is there a change in the UI?

Thank you in advance.